# How do I make a partial show a string or html input box in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, mongoid, show

I have a partial that I am creating that I want it to ask user to input user answer to a string argument as long as there is no answer already in the model for the user. If there is an answer in the model for that string then I want it to show the string instead with an edit or delete button afterwards.

Here is what I have now...

```
      <%= if @bill.cell_phone_pmt.size < 0 %>
          <input type="checkbox" value=""> Cell Phone Payment</label>
            <%= f.text_field :cell_phone_pmt, autofocus: true, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter your cell phone company name" %>
      <%= else cell_phone_pmt %>
```

Now I know this isn't right but I can't seem to get it right to show the info if available and to show the input field if nothing is in that field for that specific user.
The model is bill and cell_phone_pmt is one of the argument strings in the bill model. I am using mongoid and each bill is associated with a user and supposed to be shown on a dashboard.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Also If the checkbox is not checked then I want to ignore that string argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an array of user @bills, in the original page that loads this partial you can iterate on this array and inject each item into the partial.  That partial will load based upon the logic you've inserted customized to each object:

```
<% @bills.each do |bill| %>

  <%= render partial: "your_partial_name", locals: { bill: bill, :f => f} %>

<% end %>
```

or:

```
  <%= render partial: "your_partial_name", collection: @bills, as: bill, locals: {:f => f} %>
```

then in your partial:

```
<% if bill.cell_phone_pmt.size < 0 %>
      <input type="checkbox" value=""> Cell Phone Payment</label>
        <%= f.text_field :cell_phone_pmt, autofocus: true, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter your cell phone company name" %>
  <% else %> 
    <%= bill.cell_phone_pmt %>
<% end %>
```

Partial documentation:  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

---

Finally I noticed your comparison `array.size < 0` looks off as it will return false for both empty array and positive ones.

Let me know if that helps.